# How to creat a curved arrow from a character to other characters inside math environment?

Tags: arrow-curve

How to creat a curved arrow from a character to other characters inside math environment?
Like below picture:
[image]

Comment: What's your definition of "easy"? And please help us help you by posting a minimal compilable example of your math setup with this equation.

Comment: I have no solution for it. This from a math book that I'm reading

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple with `pstricks`: create nodes at the relevant places, and connect them with `\ncarc`. Package `auto-pst-pdf` defines the `postscript` environment and enables pstricks code to be compiled with `pdflatex` instead of the chain `latex ->dvips -> pstopdf`. Alternatively you can compile with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{postscript}\bigl(\rnode{f4}{3x^4} - \pnode[1.5ex, -0.5ex]{f3}2x^3 + \rnode{f2}{5x^2}-3\bigr)\bigl(x^3 + 4 \rnode{g2}{x^2}-\pnode[0.5ex, -0.3ex]{g1}{x} + \rnode{5}{5}\bigr)
\psset{arrows=->, nodesep=1pt, arcangle=30, linecolor=LightSteelBlue, arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1}
\ncarc[arcangleB=35]{f4}{5} \ncarc{f2}{g2}
\ncarc[arcangle=-30,]{f3}{g1}
\end{postscript} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why answering here and not at the thread marked as duplicate?

Comment: @egreg: 1) Because when I posted, no duplicate thread was marked, and 2)  albeit  I could guess there already were answers (including some from myself) on such questions, I don't know where they are.